# Get value from sum in spring

Tags: spring, rest, spring-boot

I have a problem with the result from SUM in spring. This is my code:

This is from repository class:

```
String Q="SELECT a.id_spare_part,b.kode_asset,a.kode_spare_part,a.nama_spare_part,a.tgl_beli_spare,a.vendor,b.id_asset,b.garansi,a.harga_beli,a.serial,a.stok,a.consume,sum(a.stok-a.consume)as end_balance \n" +
      "FROM spare_part a join asset b\n" +
      "where a.id_asset=b.id_asset\n" +
      "group by a.id_spare_part;";

@Query(value =Q ,nativeQuery = true)
List<spare_part> spare_Data();
```

This is my controller class:

```
@RequestMapping(path="/GetSpare", method= RequestMethod.GET)
public List<spare_part> getAll() 
{
    return (List) resp.spare_Data();
}
```

But in result I can't find end_balance  column.

Thank you.

Comment: Show your spare_part class also, it more easily for people to indentify problem that you face.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solved
In model i forget giving end_balance variable

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
String Q="SELECT a.id_spare_part, b.kode_asset, a.kode_spare_part, a.nama_spare_part, a.tgl_beli_spare, a.vendor,b.id_asset, b.garansi, a.harga_beli, a.serial, a.stok, a.consume, sum(a.stok-a.consume) as end_balance " +
  "FROM spare_part a, asset b " +
  "where a.id_asset=b.id_asset " +
  "group by a.id_spare_part";
```

Answer (score -1):

Please remove spacing here `sum(a.stok-a.consume)as end_balance`
replace the text with`sum(a.stok-a.consume) as end_balance`

Also remove all the new lines, which are not really required as part of query

Please check and let me know if it works